# How to conditionally enable and disable Cursor Pagination on Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a specific usecase where I need to make available same queryset endpoint for the frontend with and without pagination. I need to use `CursorPagination` and currently I'm just setting `pagination_class = CursorPagination` on my `*ViewSet` class.

Is there an easy way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paginator class as following example:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

YourClass():
#your code
paginator = Paginator(user_list, 10)
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this work with cursor pagination?

Comment: It is not generic from DRF. But you can try this along with other generic classes

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
You can override `page_size_query_param` variable on `CursorPagination` class. That way you can allow the frontend to set how many records it will get per page. So the frontend can use a very large number for the page size query parameter to get all the data.
Not sure if this approach has some inherent problems though.